# Rails Parse Ransack parameters with submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-parameters

I have a Rails app and using ruby 2.3.3.

For my forms I use simple_form, Ransack for the filtering and will_paginate.

I have 'set_per_page' dropdown,so Users can select if the want to see 20, 200 or 200 posts in the table.

```
= form_tag({ action: "index"}, { method: "get", id: "post_index"}) do
  =select_tag :per_page, otions_for_select( [20,200,2000], params[:per_page].to_i )
```

My javascript is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#per_page").change(function() {
    $("#post_index").submit();
  });
});
```

So when a user changes the dropdown, it will render the action 'index' again and sets the per_page parameter to the selected value. So far so good, but when I submit the Ransack parameters are gone.

When I filter with Ransack, the URL is:

```
http://localhost:3001/posts?q[name_eq]=Foo&q[title_eq]=Bar
```

When I select the 'per_page' dropdown, my URL will become:

```
http://localhost:3001/posts?per_page=200
```

How can I parse the params of the Ransack call, into the per_page call. So I will have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3001/posts?q[name_eq]=Foo&q[title_eq]=Bar&per_page=200
```

Edit:

I tried to add the Ransack parameters in a hidden field like this:

```
= form_tag({ action: "index"}, { method: "get", id: "post_index"}) do
  =select_tag :per_page, otions_for_select( [20,200,2000], params[:per_page].to_i )
  =hidden_field_tag :q, params[:q] if params[:q].present?
```

But this results in a error:

```
undefined method `merge' for "#<ActionController::Parameters:0x175c6110>":String
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add hidden_tag to ransack form and update it's value and submit on change

Add hidden tag to your form:

```
= semantic_search_form_for(@q) do |f|
    ...
    = f.hidden_field :per_page, value: params[:q][:per_page] || 20
    ...
```

Place select with per_page anywhere:

```
= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select(["20", "200", "2000"], params[:q][:per_page])
```

Add script:

```
javascript:
$('#per_page').on('change', function() {
    $('#q_per_page').val(this.value);
    $('#search').submit();
});
```

Comment: That could be an option, but I have a layout where the Ransack filtering is inside a modal. The 'per_page' dropdown is just above the table. I know it has to work somehow that I don't have to change the layout to get it work.

Comment: Now I get it! Nice! Will update my question with the anwser. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With Michael Malov's response I created this:

Inside the Ransack searchform I added:

```
= search_form_for @q do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :per_page, value: @per_page
```

The javascript is now:

```
$('#per_page').on('change', function() {
  $('#q_per_page').val(this.value);
  $('#search').submit();
});
```

The dropdown is now:

```
= form_tag({ action: "index"}, { method: "get", id: "post_index"}) do
  =select_tag :per_page, otions_for_select( [20,200,2000], @per_page )
```

Inside the controller I have:

```
@per_page = params[:q].present? ? params[:q][:per_page] : 20
```